# Using Excel Macros to reformat cell contents

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use Excel macros to change the formatting of cells. I used Google Translate for a rough translation of some subtitles for a screencast (I'm using .vtt format) but it's mucked up the formatting.

So the format I want is:

`00:00:00.000 --> 00:00:01.000`

and what it's changed it to is:

`00: 00: 00,000 -> 00: 00: 01,000`

What I have so far is:

```
ActiveCell.Select
    Dim String1 As String
    String1 = ActiveCell.Characters
    Replace(String1, " ", "") = String1
    Replace(String1, "->", " --> ") = String1
    Replace(String1, ",", ".") = String1
    ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
```

I'm then going to loop through the whole document - so selecting the cell 3 down from the edited one and performing the same operations.

What am I doing wrong that's not working? Thank you.

Comment: you are not actually resetting the value of the cell. Use `ActiveCell.Value = String1` to do that. But really, you should [avoid ActiveCell\Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and work directly with the objects. Also, looping with a count of 3 will help a lot :)

Comment: is `00: 00: 00,000 -> 00: 00: 01,000` all in one cell?

Comment: Yes it is. So I need to remove all the spaces (except for surrounding the " --> " and change the comma to a full stop, for every third cell, starting with the active cell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim String1 As String, c as range

Set c = ActiveCell
Do While Len(c.Value) > 0
    String1 = Replace(c.Value, ": ", ":")
    String1 = Replace(String1, " -> ", " --> ")
    String1 = Replace(String1, ",", ".")
    c.value = String1
    Set c = c.Offset(3, 0)
Loop
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much. I will pull this apart to learn from it. Much appreciated!!